# Medalha capelo não concedida

Tags: suporte, medalhas

Hoje eu ganhei 200 pontos de reputação mas não recebi minha **mortarboard**. Faltou algo para receber a medalha?

Eu sei que o dia se "encerra" as 21:00 daqui (Brasil), mas eu já tinha recebido 200 pts às 18:00. Abaixo um print das minhas notificações de hoje:

[image: reoutacao]

Comment: Você pode acompanhar o número de capelos ganhos, no perfil, aba participação, quadro de medalhas, click naquela engrenagem e marque a medalha épico.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sobrou algo. Você já recebeu dia 11/09. Não é uma uma medalha por dia, é apenas uma. Agora faça o mesmo em mais 48 dias e seja [Épico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/42/epic).

Comment: Bah, pensei que fosse uma medalha por dia. Realmente está tudo certo. Valeu!

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Se fosse uma por dia o bigown teria umas 300 mil delas, :p :)

Comment: E não pare por aí, depois faça o mesmo por mais 150 dias e torne-se [legendário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/43/legendary). ;)